# Two Javascript questions about (a) forms and (b) prompt windows

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have two questions about Javascript:

- **How can I prevent my fields from being cleared when I try to cancel a form submission by returning false in the onsubmit function?**

I have a form, which has the onsubmit value "**return validate()**". If validate() finds an error in the fields, it returns false, which should stop the form submission. It does, but all my fields get cleared, and the browser ignores the Javascript I run before the return statement, like document.write. Example:

```
function validate() {
//If there's an error:
document.write("Error!");
return false;       }
```

How can I prevent this?

- **Can I have  a form inside a prompt window (a popup)?**

I have not only failed to put several inputs in one Javascript prompt(), but also to put a submittable form inside a prompt window. I have a feeling that this is not possible with Javascript, and would like to know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onsubmit="return validate()"` is fine.  There must be another reason your fields are being cleared.  What does your `validate()` function do?  Unless your submit button is actually a reset() button - or there's a JavaScript error somewhere and the form is being submitted regardless (check the JavaScript console in the browser).

Comment: My validate() function doesn't work no matter what it is defined as, even when it just returns false by default.

Comment: How are you including your <script>?

Comment: I don't think it's calling your validate() function, because you would have seen a new document containing "Error!"  If the document.write was called.  If you do a document.write once the document has loaded, it starts a brand new document.

Comment: 1. "<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>". Other functions work just fine.

Comment: SORRY FOR THE MESSINESS <form action="home.html" method="POST" name="login" onsubmit="return login()">                                                  
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!">
  </form>

Comment: Have you tried step-debugging the JavaScript in IE8? (F12 -> Start debugging button -> pause button -> submit form)

Comment: Doh!  You've named your submit button 'submit'.  Try without.  You also have login() and document.login (the name of the form).  Your form will not need a name if you do `return login(this)` and `function login(form)` and you don't need to name a button anything if it's the only button on the form.

Comment: FINALLY THE CODE WORKS! Thank you so much, sorry for the caps. By the way, what does the "this" in return login(this) mean? And also, I DO need to name my button, so that I can check if it was clicked in PHP. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Great!  But naming it submit isn't so good because that conflicts with the form.submit() function.  I don't know why you need to know if the button has been clicked unless there are many buttons.  Receiving a POST request should suffice ordinarily.  `this` refers to the form element, so you're passing the form as an argument/parameter to the login function.  So instead of doing `document.login.username` in your `login()` function, you can do `form.username`, and not have to look up the login form in the HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use alert or elements inner text to display error than document.write. Document write clear the DOM and write the specified content so you will loose the form data.

Use

```
function validate() {
//If there's an error:
document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerText = 'your error message';
return false;       }
```

2) If you talking about native prompt window, then answer is no. If you  talking about JS pop--up then yes, u can put form inside pop up. Pop is just like any browser window where u can show any html page.

Comment: I don't use document.write in my code, I just used it for testing.